# Annotation based ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, annotations

I understand that the ApplicationContext can be annotation based in Spring 3.

Can anybody please share an example , so that I could refer the same.

Thanks in advance,
Vivek

EDIT - This is the XML configuration:

`<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource ">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="test" />
    <property name="password" value="test" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="mapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.test.Mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="dao" class="com.test.MapperDao">
    <property name="mapper" ref="mapper" />
</bean>
<bean id="Controller" class="com.test.Controller" />`

Comment: How about you show us how would you do it in XML and then we show you Spring 3 equivalent. Deal ?

Comment: Sure , this is my XML
`<context:annotation-config />  
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />  
<mvc:annotation-driven />  
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
<class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
<property name="username" value="test" />
<property name="password" value="test" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>`

Comment: `<bean id="mapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
<property name="mapperInterface" value="com.test.Mapper" />
<property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="dao" class="com.test.MapperDao">
<property name="mapper" ref="mapper" />
</bean>
<bean id="Controller" class="com.test.Controller"/>`

Comment: sorry.... tried by best to format the xml... but somehow it did not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been through the Spring 3 Documentation and understood the @Configuration annotation.
So issue resolved :)

Comment: Could you perhaps share with us your insights?